# How can I restrict double click on a button in my React js application?

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick

I have a button(Material-UI) in my ReactJs application. Now, the scenario is when a user clicks(too many times thou!) and call an API to insert my form data there are multiple clicks triggering which tends to insert twice, thrice or n times(depends on user clicks).
So, I basically want a proper way to accept a single click(despite of user clicking a button n times).
Can anyone suggest me a proper way of doing it.

Note: I have tried out disabling and enbaling of button on click, as well as setTimeout to call API only on single click, but it does not work. Still on production I am having issues.

So I want a proper way for implementing single click on button (let user click multiple times the button)

Answer (score 0):

Set a state variable on button click and disable the button based on the variable. So that the user will not be able to click again. And also, you can enable the button on API response.

example:

```
[disableButton, setDisableButton] = useState(false);

const submitFunction = () => {
 setDisableButton(true);
 apiCall().then(resp => {
   setDisableButton(false) // enable button on api success response
   // code on success response
 })
 .catch((error) => {
   setDisableButton(false) 
 });
}

<button onClick={() => submitFunction()} disabled={disableButton}>Submit</button>
```